# Unity Checking if object clicked prints all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying that when you click on a Object it dissapears. This object its constantly Instanciated and the problem is that if I click on one it takes all and all are destroyed. My code:

```
void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        onItemClicked();
    }

}

void onItemClicked()
{
    //Check if click
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
    {
        //Si ha dado a algo
        if (hit.transform != null)
        {
            print(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that may be due to your structure in unity

Comment: @SebastianL what do you mean?

Comment: if you delete a parent all children are also deleted

Comment: @SebastianL Yeah, but its the parent what i want to delete, because each objects with this script are different object, only are instanciated, but not child of each other  EDIT: https://gyazo.com/da1d89dc047c122302d774b9fdf016b0

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and is working correctly, I mean, remember that when you instantiated an object, they will have(unless you set it) the same name, so as the gif show, you will have multiple prints with the same name but they are actually different objects. So if you try:

```
...
if (hit.transform != null)
{
   print(hit.transform.gameObject);
   hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
...
```

You will see that only one object will turn off